# Possible to automatically materialize a result-set under certain size?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I want to 'store small results' for SQL queries, for example, an aggregation that may take 10s or so to run and only returns 100 results. Is it possible to materialize a view 'automatically' if it is under a certain size? Otherwise I think I have to run two queries.

```
select name, count(*) cnt from team group by name
-- if len(results) < AUTO_MATERIALIZE_MAX
create materialized view newview as (select name, count(*) cnt from team group by name)
```

(**Note**: It seems the `temporary` keyword isn't supported, so we'll probably remove these 'view-tables' in the background either at the end of a session or after a certain time period.)

Comment: This doesn't sound like functionality that is available in any database.  I can't even really think of a use for it, given that you either refer to the materialized view or not in any give query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's just a shortcut to retrieve results quicker the first time, that's it. Also, we cannot first store the materialized view -- as it might be a very large result-set in which case w don't want to store it since its over our 'threshold' we set at the application level.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I suppose what I'm saying is a fancy (and probably crude) way of 'controlling query cache'.